# What could prevent an IFRAME in IE from making its HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

I have page with a lot of messy 3rd party Javascript.  Using IE's Developer Tools, I've looked at the DOM and find an IFRAME that looks like this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com">
```

However, looking at a capture of network traffic, there is no request made to the url found in the src attribute: `http://www.example.com`.

Under what circumstances could IE decide not to even make the HTTP call to that URL?

Comment: Do other browsers make the request?

Comment: Yes.  However, because of all the 3rd party Javascript, I'm not 100% sure it's an apples-to-apples comparison.  For example, one of the other 3rd party scripts may render different DOM elements or call different scripts per browser.  That's why I stated the question more broadly, hoping there are some known cases where a JS-added <IFRAME> won't call its SRC.

Comment: Has the "src" attribute been modified by javascript at all, or is it the original value. Sometimes, if you change an iframe's attributes in the DOM, the source won't be updated.

Comment: Also, the main difference I know between IIS and other browsers related to how they handle iframes are the security settings on IIS. The privacy settings on IIS can potentially block some third-party (ie: iframe) contents. In particular, if the site has no P3P policy information, IIS may refuse to render the iframe (although probably the HTTP request should have gone out anyway)